# What's the best way to check if a queryset is a subset of another?

Tags: django

If there are two querysets `q1` and `q2`, what's the best way to check if `q1` is a subset of `q2` ? Or do I have to iterate the values of them ?

```
q1_id = q1.values_list('id', flat=True)
q2_id = q2.values_list('id', flat=True)
all([x in q2 for x in q1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `set` to check this:

```
q1_id = set(q1.values_list('id', flat=True))
q2_id = set(q2.values_list('id', flat=True))
issubset = q1_id.issubset(q2_id)
```